# RAILS : Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack" on installing ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5

I added `gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'` in my gemfile and did a bundle install. Then it's throwing me the following error.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
   In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
     actionpack (= 5.0.0.1)

In Gemfile:
activeadmin (~> 1.0.0.pre4) was resolved to 1.0.0.pre4, which depends on
  formtastic (~> 3.1) was resolved to 3.1.4, which depends on
    actionpack (>= 3.2.13)

activeadmin (~> 1.0.0.pre4) was resolved to 1.0.0.pre4, which depends on
  inherited_resources (~> 1.6) was resolved to 1.6.0, which depends on
    actionpack (< 5, >= 3.2)

activeadmin (~> 1.0.0.pre4) was resolved to 1.0.0.pre4, which depends on
  inherited_resources (~> 1.6) was resolved to 1.6.0, which depends on
    actionpack (< 5, >= 3.2)

activeadmin (~> 1.0.0.pre4) was resolved to 1.0.0.pre4, which depends on
  kaminari (~> 0.15) was resolved to 0.17.0, which depends on
    actionpack (>= 3.0.0)

activeadmin (~> 1.0.0.pre4) was resolved to 1.0.0.pre4, which depends on
  ransack (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.8.2, which depends on
    actionpack (>= 3.0)
```

> Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
>   the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

I did the bundle update, but still the error is the same. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

> `gem 'activeadmin'` is not compatible with rails 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution worked for me. For `rails 5` you would have to add another `gem` as follows:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources'
```

To read further, go to [this](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/4177) thread.

Comment: did that. But it's not compatible with rails 5. That's why  `gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'`

Answer (score 1):

You have to install inherited resources gem with active admin in rails 5

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources'
```